# Javascript typeof string latlng address

Tags: javascript, string, typeof

```
var str = "40.697299, -41.817628";
var str = "10 Downing Street, London";
var str = "10 Downing Street";
```

I'm trying to figure out how to differentiate between the three above. I tried `typeof` but this all output as `string` so I was wondering is there a way using Javascript to pick up if the above is an `address` or `latlng` and return it?

Comment: Define `address` and `latlng` (in terms of JS language)

Comment: @matewka well in the first 3 examples, I'd like to find out a way of detecting if each was an `address` or `coordinates` but each are being forced as a string

Comment: Not "forced". They _are_ strings. JavaScript doesn't have complex data types like "coords". You're just going to have to manually check them.

Comment: @user3770851, Cerbrus is right. All three examples are strings. Javascript doesn't distinguish geographical coordinates nor street addresses. You should introduce a pattern which defines a string as a _geographical coordinates_ (or _street address_) then perform a regular expression. But while you don't know basic variable types in JS, there's still a very long way to learn regular expressions.

Comment: It's strings. How it will be address and latlng in JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are both strings so you will have to look at the contents of them. I'd suggest using a regular expression, such as

```
function isLatLng(str) {
  return str.match(/^(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?),\s*(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?)$/) !== null;
}
```

This will return true if it is a latitude/longitude